# HTML5 boilerplate background-image doesn't show

Tags: css, html, background, background-image, html5boilerplate

I'm making a website with HTML5Boilerplate, but every time I use the css `background` or `background-image` property, the image doesn't show up.

Folders:
root/css/style.css
root/img_files/logo.png

My css code looks like this:

```
#logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 164px;
    height: 42px;
    background: url(../img_files/logo.png);
    background-repeat: none;
}
```

My stylesheet is properly added to the page:

I can't add a single background image to the objects on the page. HTML5Boilerplate has been installed, so maybe that't the problem, I'm not sure. Do you know why correct CSS and HTML doesn't display the images?

Comment: Does this work if you try it in a separate html? Try setting the background to the body (just to know if the #logo is the problem). I've just made a web with the latest h5b and seted the background image of my body with no problem...

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
background-repeat: none;
```

to

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Or just use

```
background: url(../img_files/logo.png) no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just come to the same problem and discovered that in case you'll change ID from #logo to anything else (in HTML and CSS of course), then the same code will start to work. Can't say what has been "blocking" #logo to be used, but for now I don't have enough time to discover where the problem is.

Solution for now is to use anything else than #logo, eg. #logoTop or #siteLogo

Hope that helps.

EDIT: It was a selector typo problem which caused browser had ignored that. Weird was it had not happened when selector was changed to some other name than #logo. Please note that #logo:**visible** typo (instead of visited)

```
#logo, #logo:link, #logo:visited,
#logo:active, #logo:focus, #logo:hover
{
    display: block;
    width: 340px;
    height: 150px;
    background: url(../images/design-elements.png) 0 -300px no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem & found out that if without the width & height property, image will not display.